# why css of widget fail in qscrollarea

Tags: css, qt

I use qApp->setStyleSheet to set style sheet for all widgets in the initialization, but I find that the widgets which in the QScrollArea lost the effect of the style sheet. I can't find the reason, can you help me?Thanks very much!

Comment: Please post a minimal stylesheet example so we can help you. There is nothing specific to QScrollArea that should break your stylesheets, except if you have an mistake, or another stylesheet takes precedence

Comment: QPushButton, QPushButton[type="typeOne"], QPushButton[type="typeTwo"] { height: 24; min-width: 56; border-width: 5; padding: -5 2; }
QPushButton, QPushButton[type="typeOne"]{ border-image: url("../Data/Img/darkBlue/QPushButton/typeOne/normal.png") 5; }
QPushButton:hover, QPushButton[type="typeOne"]:hover { border-image: url("../Data/Img/darkBlue/QPushButton/typeOne/hover.png") 5; }
QPushButton:pressed, QPushButton[type="typeOne"]:pressed { border-image: url("../Data/Img/darkBlue/QPushButton/typeOne/pressed.png") 5; } this is a example of QPushButton